# Maintaining GlobalProtractorConf and multiple config files

Tags: javascript, protractor

In my project, I created a `protractor.config.js` file and driving it with grunt. I would like to have one `globalProtractor.conf` and multiple `config.js` and maintain them like a child conf for executing different test suites and to skip the common things like On prepare function or multi capacities or global variables in all the conf.

In my globalprotractor.conf I have the

```
seleniumAddress: {
         selenium: 'http:......'
     },
```

I need to override this in the child conf. Is there any specific way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a great question and I guess that's a pretty reasonable requirement in huge test projects. I came up with below approach. Let me know if that works !!

Have global config at one place - **globalConf.js**

```
//Declare all your global configuration here which is common across all suites

var globalConf = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    localSeleniumStandaloneOpts: {
        jvmArgs: ["-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C://IEDriverServer_x64_2.53.1.exe"] 
    },
    framework: 'jasmine',
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000,
        includeStackTrace: true,
        isVerbose: true,
    },
    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
    },
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function(data){
            console.log(data);
        });
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
    getPageTimeout: 120000,
    afterLaunch: function (exitCode) {
    }
}   

//Export the global configuration to be called in local config files
module.exports = globalConf;
```

Then have multiple conf files which will import the globalConf and have suite specific changes

**conf1.js**

```
//Import Global Configuration file
var globalConf = require('./globalConf.js');

//Clone the global configuration object. You can follow any cloning mechanism
var localConf = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(globalConf));

//Make custom changes to suit your suite. May be add Suites or anything thats at suite level
localConf['specs'] = 'test.js';

// Set the value of exports.config based on
exports.config = localConf;
```

**conf2.js**

```
//Import Global Configuration file
var globalConf = require('./globalConf.js');

//Clone the global configuration object. You can follow any cloning mechanism
var localConf = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(globalConf));

//Make custom changes to suit your suite. May be add Suites or anything thats at suite level
localConf['specs'] = 'test2.js';

// Set the value of exports.config based on
exports.config = localConf;
```

Comment: Now in above 2 conf files with specs mentioned, how do I run them from one single conf file in protractor?